# Create view or Function which uses a Union select in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table in a SQL Server 2012 db with the following layout:

The motherID is refering to an ID in the same table

We are 100% that there is no deadlock in the table.

I have created a stored procedure which output all the ID staring from a generic ID

ie:

```
ID    MotherID
1     1
2     1
3     1
4     2
5     2
6     4
```

When I go with 1 it returns

```
1,2,3,4,5,6
```

When staring with 4

```
4, 6
```

Starting with 2

```
2,4,5,6
```

However I would like to use the outcome in a inner join of another select.

So the stored procedure must be rewritten as a view or function as far as I understand.

Can anybody help me?

Below is the stored procedure

```
ALTER PROCEDURE GetAll( @parent int)
AS
BEGIN
     SET NOCOUNT ON; 

WITH Children AS        
(

SELECT ID, MotherID FROM Test WHERE MotherID = @Parent  and ID!=@Parent
UNION ALL 

    SELECT e.ID, e.MotherID FROM Test e            
    INNER JOIN Children e2 on e.MotherID = e2.ID)              
    SELECT ID into #temp from Children  
    -- there is more here, thats why i use #temp    

    insert into #temp values (@parent )            
    select * from #temp order by id
    drop table #temp

END
GO
```

and the table:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Test](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [MotherID] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Test] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Test]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Test_Test] FOREIGN KEY([ID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Test] ([ID])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Test] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Test_Test]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Test]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Test_Test1] FOREIGN KEY([MotherID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Test] ([ID])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Test] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Test_Test1]
GO
```

---

```
ID  MotherID
1   1
2   1
3   1
4   2
5   2
6   4
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (That code is product specific.)

Comment: for the input 2,the output should be 2,4,5,6 right?

Comment: dbms: SQL 2012  and the outcome for 2 is indeed 2,4,5,6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE FUNCTION GetAll
(
    @parent INT
)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN WITH Children
       AS (SELECT ID,
                  MotherID
           FROM test
           WHERE MotherID = @parent
                 AND ID != @parent
           UNION ALL
           SELECT e.ID,
                  e.MotherID
           FROM test e
               INNER JOIN Children e2
                   ON e.MotherID = e2.ID)
SELECT @parent AS Id
UNION all
SELECT ID
FROM Children;
```

Then you could use it like:

```
Select * from GetAll(1);
```